# Navbar hide the begging of my page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Found my code here : http://www.bootply.com/9tzOS0huN7
I'm using bootstrap.

I guess I've a css problem : My content didn't go on the same horizontal line on the left and right part. Despite :

```
 body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

If you reduce the window size (only in width), my content'll be hidden by the navbar.. How did I fix it? I've tried many things like padding/margin and some classes of bootstrap without found an issue..

I'm pretty newbie in the CSS World.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.part-content{
    padding-top:50px;   
 }
```

Change the value to pixel instead of percent.

Comment: One day I'll understood how CSS work.. Thanks, works as I wanted !